# Can metamagic be applied to a spell delivered by a familiar?

Tags: dnd-5e, familiars, sorcerer, metamagic

I have recently created a [Divine Soul Sorcerer](https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/classes/sorcerer#DivineSoul) (XGtE, p. 50) and plan on taking the [Magic Initiate](https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/feats/magic-initiate) feat (PHB, p. 168) where my lvl 1 spell would be [*find familiar*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/find-familiar). Now as it states this familiar can be a focal point for your touch spells (like [*death ward*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/death-ward) for me).

**Can I apply metamagic options to spells delivered through the familiar?**

For example: My familiar is close to 2 of my allies. Can I at this point make it cast a twinned *death ward* to make both my allies warded?

Comment: Related: [Does Distant Spell work when casting through Familiars?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/71563/33707)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

## Spells cast through the Familiar can employ Metamagic

Find familiar states:

> ...when you Cast a Spell with a range of touch, your familiar can deliver the spell as if it had cast the spell

The function of the familiar is extending the range of your touch spells, however you are still casting the spell. Note that:

> If the spell requires an Attack roll, you use your Attack modifier for the roll.

So the caster's stats still apply. Provided the spell meets the requirements for the familiar to transfer it (touch range) and the relevant metamagic to be applied (in this case, affecting a single target), both effects can be used together. So you could use the Twinned Spell Metamagic, provided your familiar is able to touch both targets.

Answer (score 14):

## Yes, for most available options

PHB 240, **emphasis mine**:

> ...when you cast a spell of range touch, your familiar can deliver the spell **as if** it had cast the spell.

Because each metamagic option begins with "When you cast a spell" or "When you roll damage for a spell", the familiar can deliver your metamagicked spells, because the familiar is not casting the spell, it is delivering the spell you cast *as if* it had cast it.

**This does not work with Distant Spell**. Distant spell changes the range from touch to have some range ([see this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/71563/does-distant-spell-work-when-casting-through-familiars)), so the familiar cannot cast a touch spell that has been made *distant*.

**Note**: If a metamagic option is ever released that uses different language, this answer may not apply because instead of the language "When you cast a spell" being in the Metamagic feature, it is in each of the Metamagic options. Language that may change this answer could be: "When you touch a creature while casting a spell with range touch" or something similar.

Answer (score 5):

## Yes, you’re still the caster

Familiars only deliver the touch; they don’t become the caster. You cast the spell, including any metamagic, and the familiar can deliver it as part of *your* casting process.