# Can the Infiltrator model's benefit of the Armorer Artificer's 15th-level Perfected Armor feature be stacked?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, stacking, artificer

The description of the Infiltrator model's benefit for the [Armorer artificer](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/artificer#Armorer)'s [Perfected Armor](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/artificer#PerfectedArmor-2985710) feature says (*Tasha's Cauldron of Everything*, p. 17):

> ***Infiltrator.*** Any creature that takes lightning damage from your Lightning Launcher glimmers with magical light until the start of your next turn. The glimmering creature sheds dim light in a 5-foot radius, and it has disadvantage on attack rolls against you, as the light jolts it if it attacks you. In addition, the next attack roll against it has advantage, and if that attack hits, the target takes an extra 1d6 lightning damage.

It seems like the intent was that with Extra Attack, you will consume your first attack, and only your second attack will be viable to apply this effect if you hit first. However, through *haste*, Action Surge, etc., if you are to gain another attack, would you be able to chain this twice in your turn? That is, assuming you hit would you:

1. Apply effect via hit.
2. Roll second attack with advantage and deal an extra 1d6.
3. Repeat step 2 with a third attack.
4. The effect is again applied, leaving others to benefit from the advantage and extra 1d6 damage again after your turn.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

## That works fine

The phrase it uses is, *"...the next attack roll against it..."*. There is no implication that it has to be *your* attack, just an attack roll.

### Remember, not all attacks hit

So another way to look at this would be if your first attack didn't hit, but your second attack does. It would still leave the creature in the same glowy state with advantage on the next attack from someone else farther along the initiative order.

### You also don't have to attack the same creature

There is no rule saying that you need to use your second attack to go after the creature you lit up on your first attack. So you could hit two different creatures, setting them up for a rogue with sneak attack or a paladin with smite. What would be better? Your one launcher extra attack, or setting up a second creature for the rogue to hit and add 8d6 sneak attack damage?

---

Since it was brought up by the OP in comments...

### Stacking is not an issue

Per the Player's Handbook on [combining effect](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/phb/spellcasting#CombiningMagicalEffects):

> The effects of the same spell cast multiple times don’t combine, however. Instead, the most potent effect — such as the highest bonus — from those castings applies while their durations overlap, **or the most recent effect** applies if the castings are equally potent and their durations overlap.

After the first hit, there are two effects going, glimmering and the advantage. Hitting a second time with the Lightning Launcher doesn't increase the range, the brightness, or any other effect. It doesn't stack in terms of features. Instead, it is merely the most recent effect and lasts as long as it lasts; the beginning of the character's next turn.

Similarly, the advantage ends when someone makes an attack roll; including the artificer. So when you hit with your second attack, there is nothing to stack, the advantage effect has already ended.

Comment: I'm aware not every attack hits, obviously it doesn't work when you miss. I'm aware of the cooperative implications, I just wanted to know from a theoretical standpoint if it was possible. For example, if there was only one enemy in range, your teammates in range have mostly save based spells, etc. What I was really hoping to see was RAW justification for why it would apply the advantage and damage effect again if the glowing effect continues until your next turn

Comment: @KakunaRattata, RAW, yes it works because nothing stops the glowing except reaching your next turn, and nothing limits who makes the next attack and gains advantage. Just be aware that the glowing and the advantage are two different things. _"**In addition**, the next attack roll against it has advantage, and if that attack hits, the target takes an extra 1d6 lightning damage."_ Not "While glimmering", just "In addition" to the whole glimmering status, the next attack gains advantage. Even if that next attack happens after the glimmering fades.

Comment: Is that really the intention? The advantage lasts indefinitely? I read that as 3 different effects of the attack, all part of the "glimmering" effect.

Comment: @KakunaRattata *Technically,* the text doesn't link the glow to the advantage+damage; but I would say the *intent* is that the glimmer carries all the effects with it and they all end on your next turn if not expended earlier. I expect they split it that way to make sure it was clear that the adv+dmg was a one-time thing while the other effects last until your turn. It probably should have said "the next attack roll against it while it glows..." but since that's pretty wordy I'm not shocked that they didn't think of it.

Comment: @DarthPseudonym, that's why is said "While glimmering". It would have been very concise and clear what the intend is. But since they chose "In addition", it's a little ambivalent but leans towards being a separate thing.

Comment: Back to the point, is this not a case of "effects of the same name don't stack?" why or why not? Can that please be included in your answer?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. The advantage/damage effect can't stack because any attack made to apply it again would expend the previous instance of it, and the disadvantage/glow effect won't stack because you can only have disadvantage once and, well, if you're glowing with a five foot radius for three reasons... you're still glowing with a five foot radius. There's no need to invoke any special rules.

Comment: @KakunaRattata, have my recent changes clarified everything?

Comment: Yes, my thought was the glowing effect continues after the advantage is consumed, and if that's part of the same effect, the combining effects rule applied. But it would just refresh the effect anyway. That rule is for spell stacking though. I had thought I saw another rule. I'm basically asking about this rule https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/140597/do-the-rules-for-combining-magical-effects-apply-to-non-spell-effects